# Get an email form a String with dots and number using R

Tags: r, string, email

I have the following string `theText <- "one123.4@xyz.eu, name.name2@abc.com, ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk, xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"`

I want to get the email addresses. I cannot get the first email, to get the other I wrote this:

```
theText <- "one123.4@xyz.eu, name.name2@abc.com, ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk, xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
emailsTT = regmatches(theText, gregexpr("([_+a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_+a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,14}))", theText))
emailsTT
```

And the results is:

```
"4@xyz.eu"            "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"   "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

As you can see the results of the first one is not correct.

Any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scan` to read the emails then trim the whitespaces with `trimws`:

```
trimws(scan(text = theText, what="character", sep = ","))

[1] "one123.4@xyz.eu"     "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"  
[4] "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

You could also do:

```
 unlist(regmatches(theText, gregexpr("[_+a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+[_+a-z0-9.-]*", theText)))
[1] "one123.4@xyz.eu"     "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"  
[4] "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

Comment: Thank you very mucho Onyambu. It is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CSV string *only* contains email addresses, then a simple string split would be easier:

```r
theText <- "one123.4@xyz.eu, name.name2@abc.com, ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk, xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
emails <- strsplit(theText, ",\\s*")[[1]]
emails

[1] "one123.4@xyz.eu"     "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"  
[4] "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

**Edit:**

If you instead need to fish these email addresses from a larger text, then a simple regex pattern to use might be:

```
\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b
```

We can try using `regmatches` along with `regexpr` here for a base R solution:

```
regmatches(theText, gregexpr("\\b\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+\\b", theText))[[1]]

[1] "one123.4@xyz.eu"     "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"  
[4] "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

Comment: Sorry Tim, my mistake the email addresses come with a lot of other text. I run your code and the result it is not what I looking for. Regards

Comment: @LuisMoncayo I was unaware of this, as your original question did not make this clear.  Check the updated answer for a base R approach to find the emails.  You might need to adjust the regex used for email addresses, but the internet is rife with many examples for this already.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided you could use the regex :

```
stringr::str_extract_all(theText, '[a-zA-Z0-9].*?@\\w+\\.\\w+')[[1]]
#[1] "one123.4@xyz.eu"     "name.name2@abc.com"  "ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk"  
#     "xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"
```

If `theText` only consists comma-separated values of email you can also use `read.csv` to read the data as dataframe.

```
unlist(read.csv(text = theText, header = FALSE), use.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry Ronak, My mistake the email addresses come with a lot of other text. I run your code and the result it is not what I looking for. Regars

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer. Now, assuming there might be text beyond e-mails, and the dots are the only characters giving you the trouble:

```
library(tidyverse)

theText <- "one123.4@xyz.eu, name.name2@abc.com, ton.mar_Xe@xyz.uk, xxx_yyy_123@opq.edu"

e_mails <- str_extract_all(theText,'[\\w|\\.]*@[\\w|\\.]*')

e_mails_df <- e_mails %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(e_mail = value)
```

Comment: Sorry benjasast I cannot manage to run your code. I cannot tell you if it outputs what I am looking for

Comment: forgot to mention, library(tidyverse) is neccesary.